# Matlab - how can i filter an table of dates

Tags: arrays, matlab, date, filter

I have a problem on Matlab
I have an table of dates (1 columns and hundreds of rows) and I want to keep only the dates that are superior to a given date.

You will find the first ten rows of the table

```
a =

  17×1 table

  nav_date  
____________

'2018-02-09'
'2018-02-12'
'2018-02-08'
'2018-02-13'
'2018-02-14'
'2018-02-15'
'2018-02-16'
'2018-02-19'
'2018-02-20'
'2018-02-21'
'2018-02-22'
'2018-02-01'
'2018-02-02'
'2018-02-05'
'2018-02-06'
'2018-02-07'
'2018-02-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `datenum` to converts the datetime to serial date numbers. Then use a logical index:

```
T  = yourtable;
df = 'YYYY-mm-dd'; %date format
dl = '2018-02-20'; %date limit
T(datenum(T.nav_date,df)>datenum(dl,df),:)
```